Stateful Widget does not receive data passed to its constructor from proceeding
I've spent around 5 hours debugging the connectivity between two widgets that cease to function at the passthrough point for receiving the data. I've looked on stackoverflow and none of the answers worked with the latest build of flutter. How can I get the data to pass between two stateful widgets or more?
I tried to initialize the variables for the faulty widget but received errors further down the line.
// Works
class ClientPortal extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClientPortal({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<ClientPortal> createState() => _ClientPortalState();
}

class _ClientPortalState extends State<ClientPortal> {
  // State Variables
  dynamic userData;
  dynamic dataCount;

  fetchClientPortalData() async {
    final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    final storageObj = await storage.readAll();
    var uid = storageObj['uid'];
    var accessToken = storageObj['access_token'];
    var client = storageObj['client'];

    try {
      Response response = await post(
          Uri.parse('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/clients/client_portal'),
          body: {'uid': uid, 'access-token': accessToken, 'client': client});
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var clientPortalData = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
        var responseHeaders = response.headers;
        setState(() {
          dataCount = clientPortalData['dataCount'];
          userData = clientPortalData['userData'];
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  late Future<dynamic> _clientPortalData;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _clientPortalData = fetchClientPortalData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
      future: _clientPortalData,
      initialData: {},
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List<Widget> children;
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          print('INSIDE OF CLIENT PORTAL');
         // works start
            print(userData);
        // works end

           // fails to store data attributes here in widget below
          return PortalNavigator(
              dataCount: dataCount,
              userData: userData);
        } else {
        }
        return Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: children,
        ));
      },
    );
  }
}


// THIS WIDGET DOES NOT RECEIVE DATA
class PortalNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  PortalNavigator(
      {super.key,
              dataCount: dataCount,
              userData: userData});

  @override
  State<PortalNavigator> createState() => _PortalNavigatorState();
}


class _PortalNavigatorState extends State<PortalNavigator> {
  dynamic userData;
  dynamic dataCount;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('NO DATA EXIST FOR VARS ABOVE');
   print(userData);
   print(dataCount);

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: PortalNavigatorView(
              dataCount: dataCount,
              userData: userData),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class PortalNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  PortalNavigator(
      {super.key,
      dataCount, userData});

  @override
  State<PortalNavigator> createState() => _PortalNavigatorState();
}


When you want to get data from the parent widget, its enough to define the parameters in the Constructor. So first of all you can remove the userData and dataCount from this class _PortalNavigatorState extends State<PortalNavigator> class.
Whenever you want to use the received data, call it like widget.userData and widget.dataCount. The widget keyword is essential to call constructor parameters in every stateful widgets.
class PortalNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  PortalNavigator(
      {super.key,
              required this.dataCount,
              required this.userData});
    final dynamic dataCount;
    final dynamic userData;

  @override
  State<PortalNavigator> createState() => _PortalNavigatorState();
}


class _PortalNavigatorState extends State<PortalNavigator> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('NO DATA EXIST FOR VARS ABOVE');
   print(widget.userData);
   print(widget.dataCount);

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: PortalNavigatorView(
              dataCount: widget.dataCount,
              userData: widget.userData),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class PortalNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  PortalNavigator(
      {super.key,
      required this.userData,
required this.dataCount});
final dynamic userData;
final dynamic dataCount;

  @override
  State<PortalNavigator> createState() => _PortalNavigatorState();
}


Thank you for your advice -- all widgets are now receiving data

@DWCod3r, welcome to stackoverflow. Just a hint: Instead of a thank you message, you could accept the answer, if it solved your issue. That way saman, gets his deserved credit and your question is marked as answered.

I did try -- I don't have enough reputation points, unfortunately.

@DWCod3r The upvote is different form choosing an answer as an accepted one. We need some reputation to upvote different answer but I think you as a question owner can choose any answer as your accepted answer.

I've accepted the answer.
